# Access to undeclared static property: Gedmo\Uploadable\Mapping\Validator::$validateWritableDirectory Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, stofdoctrineextensions

please, why it wrotes me this error: ** Access to undeclared static property: Gedmo\Uploadable\Mapping\Validator::$validateWritableDirectory**  ?? 
My files:

- http://pastebin.com/s4VzMZW7   config.yml
- http://pastebin.com/JqfkmAEy   composer.json
- http://pastebin.com/btbPpz2V   AppKernel.php

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the composer.json

change this two lines:

```
"gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "v2.3.2",
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev"
```

to this one:

```
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "v1.1.0"
```

In my case it was helpful.